# I am utilizing the bedrock Llama2 LLM with langchain and I aim to integrate a stop feature. How can this be achieved?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

> I am utilizing the bedrock Llama2 LLM with langchain and I aim to
> integrate a stop feature. How can this be achieved?